# Down-Vote Attack

Tags: support, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Attacked by Downvotes; what do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/attacked-by-downvotes-what-do-i-do)

So, I've experienced my first down-vote attack. For some reason, a user is going through my recent answers and down-voting all of them. He/she has down-voted 9 of my recent answers in the last 3 minutes. Obviously, they couldn't have read all those answers in three minutes. Also, they were great answers :)

Can anything be done to prevent such behavior? Can anything be done to challenge a down-vote attack?

Additional Info: I rarely down-vote. I can't imagine this is a "revenge" down-vote attack.

Comment: @Rosinante, thanks for the heads up. I did look for similar posts, though I never would have thought to check for "Serial downvotes in quick succession" :)

Comment: And none of the related questions that popped up that were an exact duplicate of this helped you in any way, my unique snowflake?

Comment: @eternalseptember, Actually, no. I've noticed that people tend to get grumpy when you post a duplicate question. Since I didn't know that this was called "serial downvoting", my title read: "Down-Vote Attack". That title does not bring up the dupes. My apologies. Should I delete the question or leave it in for the goobers like me that don't know the correct terminology?

Comment: @JamesHill: Leave the post, and don't worry about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an automatic script that runs every 24 hours that removes such voting sprees. This is the primary defense against such behaviour.

Just wait for at least a day and you should see those votes removed if they were really from the same user.