# Is it a coincidence or am I down-voted deliberately?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, abuse, serial-voting

On [PHP modify TXT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937436/php-modify-txt-file/9937525#9937525) my answer was down-voted first. Then up-voted twice. It took some time before it gets fixed on +1. Because in the mean time this answer had many events like *up-vote, down-vote, un-down-vote, up-up-vote*.

After that I noticed my reputation increased by 10. Then after some more time I noticed its reduced by 10.  So I though someone un-up-voted it. But **no**. It was *5 down-vote* at the same time. 4 of them came from very old post of mine. Some of them are correct answers.

[image]

Was this a coincidence or was I down-voted deliberately?

Comment: It (4 downvotes within a minute!) *certainly* seems suspicious; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/i-was-just-attacked-by-an-onslaught-of-downvotes-what-do-i-do

Comment: today someone downvoted my 22 answers, hope vote anomaly script will correct everything.

Comment: @Reniuz - that'll definitely be reversed tonight as well.

Comment: @Reniuz your profile's reputation tab looks more verbose!

Comment: Yeah...someone calms down in interesting way :)

Comment: Its your fault for being a PHP developer.  Don't you know how cranky they tend to be?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This was deliberate, and would be caught tonight when we check for this sort of behavior.  Just for kicks I invoked the job early to make sure, which reversed this serial downvote spree.

Note: I was *actually testing* some behavior here, don't use this answer as a reason to request a dev to this...it runs every night and that's enough.

Comment: I just noticed a *reversal* on my profile. And I think its better to wait as of @Matt's comment on my question.

Comment: `would be caught` meaning, the downvoter will be known?

Comment: `when we check for this sort of behavior` For some reason, the usage of `we` invoked an image of the SE team peeking under floorboards for serial downvoting. :/

Comment: @PresleyDias Even if they do, the information will not be made public.

Comment: @Alenanno ok but then what happens?, only the downvotes are reversed ?

Comment: @PresleyDias I suppose they'll warn the user to avoid having such not constructive behavior. If users keep downvoting just as a sort of revenge thing (multiple times — for a single case a warning is enough), they can end up being suspended for that.

Comment: @PresleyDias Also up-votes get reversed.

Comment: @Alenanno, the warning-the-user part is a bold assumption. I'd assume no such thing.

Comment: @Alenanno oook got it, `they can end up being suspended for that` is better i gues in extreme cases

Comment: @Arjan Not at all. PresleyDias, yes, when it starts to be more than a one-case thing.

Comment: Okay, @Alenanno, any reference for that then?

Comment: @Arjan I can't give you details, obviously, but it happened to me. I mean, I was serially down-voted and the user got a warning.

Comment: @Arjan Serial voting (up/down) is disruptive behaviour, and typically the moderators will contact the user privately the first time, or suspend if the behaviour persists.

Comment: @YannisRizos I'd really want to know how moderators contact personally? because there is no messaging system in SE sites.

Comment: @Shiplu Moderators have access to a tool to contact users privately. These messages are seen only by the user who is being contacted, the moderators of the site (all of them, not just the one who send the message) and of course Stack Exchange employees. If a moderator contacts you that way, you will receive the message the next time you log into the site. Alternatively moderators can create private chat rooms and invite users to them. Both methods are reserved for serious moderation related issues.

Comment: ah that makes sense.

Comment: @Alenanno I can categorically confirm that the offender is *not* always contacted in some way. I would guess it's only when a certain level has been breached where it goes from, "this looks odd" to, "this is clearly, obviously, extreme abuse".

Comment: That is: sometimes the automated system will reverse votes, but no further action is immediately taken.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I didn't say it *always* happens. I am not able to confirm that. I just said that it's not unusual that the serial down-voter gets a warning. By warning I mean a message from the SE team to refrain from such behavior. When a user down-votes many or even all of your answers and questions in a relatively short time, then we're way far from the "this looks odd" phase. :P

Comment: You guys should get a chat room instead of spamming my global inbox :)

Comment: @NickCraver Ooops! Sorry! :D