# Finding the serial downvoter!

Tags: discussion, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I was just attacked by an onslaught of downvotes! What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/i-was-just-attacked-by-an-onslaught-of-downvotes-what-do-i-do)

This happened to me just today on several perfectly good answers (some accepted). Is there any privilege which when unlocked can be used to find who did this? What is SO's answer to serial downvoting as of now?

[image]

Comment: The answer is automatic reversal of serial votes (up or down).

Comment: Nope. The serial down voting will usually be reversed at UTC midnight. If not, flag one of your post and contact moderator.

Comment: I've warned the user. The only thing left to do now is wait for the script to reverse the votes automatically.

Comment: Don't bother... you won't find any of that information.

Comment: Is there a way to find out WHO did the serial down/up-voting?

Comment: @ganders Only moderators can do that.