# Should I Be Suspicious? Sequential Downvotes

Tags: discussion, down-votes, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I was just attacked by an onslaught of downvotes! What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/i-was-just-attacked-by-an-onslaught-of-downvotes-what-do-i-do)
>   [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Today I woke up to this:

[image: Photo detailing what I saw]

As you can see, someone downvoted different questions (My answer on those questions was marked as "accepted" on each of them) at the same time. Furthermore, all these questions are from over a month ago, each with multiple upvotes.

I'm not worried about the reputation, I'm just wondering if this has been seen before.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This is a duplicate. I apologize for not knowing what it's called. I searched for it, but didn't come across the "serial downvoting" term.

Comment: Well, you closely missed the term, which, I guess, caused the dupes to not appear in the "Questions that may already have your answer" list. No harm, though. Dupes happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been seen again and again, it's called serial downvoting.

Every night at midnight UTC a script runs that detects such serial votes (both up and down) and undoes them. If this doesn't happen for you, flag one of the downvoted posts for moderator attention, explaining that you suspect serial downvoting, and they'll see what they can do for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply!