# Getting Downvotes on old questions as a reward for pointing out something useful

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I was just attacked by an onslaught of downvotes! What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/i-was-just-attacked-by-an-onslaught-of-downvotes-what-do-i-do)

I've just received 3 downvotes in rapid succession on old questions, most likely just because I pointed out "copied" content as a comment in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539011/how-to-format-the-datetime/14539039#comment20277957_14539039) .

Is such downvoting to be expected and is it acceptable behaviour?

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [I was just attacked by an onslaught of downvotes! What do I do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21575/182513)

Comment: @Bart: The plagiarism was real (in my view), and the 3 downvotes do look retaliatory. I fear that in this case the OP has a case and coming here was the right thing to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you shouldn't.  Looking at your reputation history, I would strongly suspect that the serial voting cleanup script will revert these voting changes by tomorrow.

If you don't get your reputation back, ping at me (or another moderator) here and we can ask someone to look at it and roll it back if it is indeed all from the same person.

**No, this is not the norm, nor is it condoned behavior.**

The focus should be on the post, not the user.

Comment: [Condoned](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/condoned)—I learned a new word today! :-)

Comment: @casperOne what if the DownVotes weren't serial?

Comment: @AbZy The script will remove upvotes that seem to be heavily favored towards a user instead of the posts.  If you go through and rapidly upvote a user's content, it's obvious that the vote is because you like the person and not the content.  We want votes to (try to) be a representation of usefulness, and that representation is skewed if people vote for the person and not the post.

Answer (score 5):

You can flag and should flag the post for moderator attention, pointing out the plagiarism (which in this case is small, but it could be a sign of more endemic copying behaviour). I agree the post is a straight copy (down to the error that Soner edited out).

The retaliation you received is not normal behaviour either. With only 3 downvotes, it may slip by the serial-vote detection. If the votes have indeed not been reverted by tomorrow, ask a moderator to look into it.

Comment: I did say "nitpicking".

Comment: @casperOne: I flicked the nick right back. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes , First thing I actually did was flagging the post. And Thanks I would hope they don't slip by :-)