# Downvote feast on my profile

Tags: support, voting, tag-abuse

I just got downvoted on alot of my questions and answers in a very short period of time on SO. I suspect someone hold a grudge on me.

- Is there any way of identifying that person?
- Do I have to go to war with that person or is there a more civil way
  to resolve the dispute? If he/(she -very unlikely :-))  continuous
  his attacks my reputation will hit 0 one day.

I've seen similar questions, but non about identifying the aggressor.

Comment: Related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21580/201262

Comment: Voting is anonymous, though if this person keeps offending, we will be notified and deal with them directly. No need for you to know who it is or get involved. Possibly someone who didn't like your literature.

Comment: I took a look, and this was rather egregious. Action has been taken.

Comment: Bear in mind downvoting costs the downvoter -1, so the odds of their persisting over the long term is unlikely. Have you had a dispute with someone on the site, or has someone drawn attention to negative features about your posts in general (e.g. spelling/grammar/case)?

Comment: @halfer - downvotes on questions cost nothing.

Comment: Please don't see this as an invitation to downvote my question :-)

Comment: I have the same question , just that Franz was the first to post !

Comment: @TimPost see above comment