# I've been revenge-voted, help?

Tags: support, voting, down-votes, serial-voting

I downvoted someone, and then they got angry with me, so they downvoted me within 2 minutes. They were all random questions (I think actually my top 9 questions). They got reversed. No matter, downvoted again yesterday. Reversed. And nope, still downvoting me.
Proof: 
[image: Downvotes and reversals.]

Now, I have a feeling this guy isn't going to give up for quite a while.

I've seen all the posts on serial downvotes, but this is persistent, and I don't think it has been covered before.

Can anyone help me on what to do?

Comment: Just ignore it? He will get tired after a while.

Comment: The downvoter will get noticed and suspended for voting irregularities.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Please read the WHOLE post, not just the start. It's not just the downvotes, it's the consistency.

Comment: @ofstream [From the duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21580/159251): "If you think there is still a problem, flag for a ♦ moderator (or add a comment here), or e-mail the team (page footer)."

Comment: On two of the three days, you get your rep back as a result of rolling back serial downvoting.  I wouldn't sweat it.

Comment: @Oded Not exactly... The automatic vote reversal will take care of things for a while, but it's not like anybody is notified when it happens. Raising a flag for a moderator or emailing us in cases of really persistent downvoting is the way to go. The latter is usually more efficient, since we have access to the information moderators don't that makes investigating these cases a lot easier. Coming to meta is probably the least efficient thing to do in this case, but right now it worked out either way. I'm handling the downvoter. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear - Good point. Reading my comment does suggest this is automatic, though I did mean that by posting a Meta question we have been notified.

Comment: @AnnaLear Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can basically ignore this behavior. It will stop after a while... there are penalties for repeatedly serially voting. (Edit: As per Oded's comment, they will be suspended for voting irregularities if they persist.) Also, they're probably going to get bored with it.

In short, you don't need to do anything. Serial downvotes are reversed automagically by the system within 24 hours. Make sure you've read [this FAQ question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) on serial voting.

Comment: The OP is aware of this. Just that the other user is persistent.

Comment: I did notice that, I did comment on it, and it is on my image. However, he refuses to stop downvoting. That's my issue.

Comment: They will stop after a while. I'm pretty sure there's an automatic suspension or voting ban, but don't hold me to that one. I can't find a reference to it anywhere, though I'm pretty sure it exists.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi Is there? I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @ofstream See Oded's comment above. Looks like an automatic suspension.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi There are no automatic suspensions for serial voting. They're all manual.