# What can I do about downvotes cast in retaliation?

Tags: support, down-votes

A user posted an answer on Stack Overflow which was incorrect.

I downvoted it (and upvoted the other correct answer besides my own), and told him why I downvoted it, and he proceeded to downvote my answer, unjustly.

What can I do about this? What are my options?

Comment: How can you be sure that adeneo was the one downvoting you?

Comment: It is only a -2 hit in rep... I'd say let it go and move on.

Comment: This is my advice: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124708/225020

Comment: @hjpotter92 - Because I went to his profile immediately afterwards, and it showed -1 and -2 for that question, and his and mine were the only 2 with downvotes

Comment: Yet those are all assumptions. You can't know for sure, and it doesn't matter. There are no options but to move on.

Comment: @Damien - it's not about the points, it's about fostering a community that's about help, and not about revenge

Comment: @Bart - if there are only 2 downvotes on all answers, and one is his, and he's showing a -2 for the downvote I gave him and a -1 for giving a downvote, the only possible conclusion is that he gave me the downvote.  This is not an assumption.  It's simple logic.

Comment: @TheSmose but not conclusive logic at all. I would not worry about it, take the higher ground and move on.

Comment: Even so, move on. There is nothing that can, nor should be done about it. Users are free to vote how they see fit, barring serial votes and vote fraud. Even then, don't confront the user.

Comment: @Bart - Fair enough...

Comment: @TheSmose as downvotes are anonymous, all you have are assumptions. Let it go and continue helping other people.

Comment: Ah @TheSmose you remind me so much of myself.. I know how you feel.. it's just not worth getting worked up about, and you don't know if he gave you  the downvote.. trust me- I have gotten so worked up about things that don't matter (and probably will again - wish I wouldn't). it's but a drop in the ocean my dear

Comment: And yet you still base all of that on assumptions. It's a single downvote. You got several upvotes as well, which weigh more heavily. Downvotes happen. Move on.

Comment: It's not conclusive logic at all. There are *lots* of users browsing any given page on Stack Overflow at any given time. It's equally as likely that someone else saw your answer and downvoted it. (They don't even necessarily have to see it on the question page—it could have appeared in a review queue somewhere!)

Comment: Also, this is why most of us have stopped leaving comments when we downvote other people's posts.

Comment: @CodyGray - When you give or receive a downvote to an answer, it shows in your profile. In his profile, it showed "-2 downvote Regular expression for Dutch zipcode" for the downvote I gave him, and "-1 downvoted Regular expression for Dutch zipcode" for GIVING a downvote. He and I were the only 2 users with downvotes, and he couldn't have downvoted himself. The conclusion is that he got the -1 for downvoting me.

Comment: @TheSmose Since when can you see when users have cast a downvote? That's not possible. (and if it was, that's a bug) Take a screenshot of it and show us.

Comment: You can see in *your own profile* when *you* have cast a downvote. That information is not part of your *public* profile, and other users cannot see it. (Check in your browser's "private" mode if you want to see for yourself.) Or check out [my Stack Overflow profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray?tab=reputation)—no downvotes visible there, but I'll disclose that I've downvoted at least a couple of posts today.

Comment: Ah... haha... I must have looked at my own activity list by accident.  OOPS!!!

Comment: Ok, this question sucks... I'm removing it

Comment: You can't. It has an upvoted answer.

Comment: Oh that sucks. :)

Comment: @TheSmose hahahahhahah OMG are you sure we're not related, the number of times I've done this... I gave you a sympathetic upvote.. hm hope Bart doesn't read this

Comment: Don't worry @Skippy. I haven't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What can I do about this?

Move on.

> Is there a way that I can contact him directly to confront him about it?

About what? Downvotes are **anonymous**.

Comment: *"-1 downvoted Regular expression for Dutch zipcode" for GIVING a downvote* -- if true, then that is a bug, which I can hardly imagine nobody noticed yet. (Go into some private browsing/ingocnito mode and look at your own profile.)

Comment: @TheSmose Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: Nevermind... see main comments.  I think I looked at my own profile instead of his.

Comment: PS - checkmark for you.  Sorry for being an idiot. :)

Comment: @TheSmose How do you feel about retaliatory upvotes? ;)

Comment: @AsheeshR - Hah! :)